# How do you remove app icons from screens on a Galaxy Pocket?

Tags: samsung

Just how the heck do I remove unwanted app icons from my home and other screens? On my Galaxy S4 I just slid them off the side, but on the damned Galaxy Pocket, they just bounce off the side back onto the screen, or slide across to the next screen.

Do I have to use Applications Manager and actually uninstall them, or is there some better way?

Comment: When you start to slide them does a trash can or X appear on the top?

Comment: Oops, never saw the trash can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you long press the icon you will see a trash can. To remove them from the screen, drop them on it.